# Android web view does not load specific url

Tags: android, webview, geolocation

The application that I wrote load some websites but It does not load my web site. I have installed ssl sertificate which is purchased from namecheap.com. It is secure now but still web view does not load it. What might be the problem? Thanks.

Code is below;

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin, final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt()");

            final boolean remember = false;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WebActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Locations Permission");
            builder.setMessage("Would like to use your Current Location ")
                    .setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // origin, allow, remember
                    callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Don't Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // origin, allow, remember
                    callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://edumaster.me/");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which is below solved my first problem.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
});
```

Comment: This effectively disables the SSL/TLS protection and is therefore inherently insecure. Don't do this.